Evaluating $ \sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+9\sqrt{1+16\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}} $
The remarkable Ramanujan nested radical is
$ \sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}}=3 $
What can be said about
$ \sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+9\sqrt{1+16\sqrt{1+\cdots}}}} $ ?
With Mathematica I found that the value is approximately $ 7.7007509\ldots $ Is there a closed form?
Of course it is easy to find a lower bound, because if we turn all the $1$'s to $0$ we have
$ A=\prod_{n=1}^\infty n^{1/{2^{n-2}}} $
And the result is $ A=e^{-4\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)} = 7.624263224...$
with the derivative of the polylogarithm function. $ A$ is the forth power of Somos's Quadratic Recurrence Constant

What is the continued fraction expansion for your number?

@WillJagy I computer other decimals too, and it's something like  [7; 1, 1, 1, 51, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1, 1, 5, 1, 4, 2, 1]

How did you get your $7.6645432624\ldots$? I get something closer to $7.7007509\ldots$ though I may have made an error.

I also got around 7.7008. for i = 1:50; x = vpa(1);  for j = i:-1:2;   x = sqrt(vpa(1) +vpa( j)^2 * x);   end ; disp(x); end

@Henry ops, you are right! Thanks for checking I edit

The approach here may help: https://www.cantorsparadise.com/ramanujans-nested-radical-problem-f14c3060e495

Another comment, not an answer. I have listed below the ‘primitive’ forms with all positive terms and the first term as small as possible, satisfying  $${I_n}^2=an^2+bn+c+(d+en)\sqrt{I_{n+1}}$$
$$2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+…...}}}}}}$$
$$2=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5+\sqrt{11+\sqrt{19+\sqrt{29+\sqrt{41+…...}}}}}}$$
$$3=\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+\sqrt{6+…...}}}}}}$$
$$3=\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+4\sqrt{1+5\sqrt{1+6\sqrt{1+…...}}}}}}$$
$$3=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{51+\sqrt{151+\sqrt{301+\sqrt{501+\sqrt{751+…...}}}}}}$$
$$3=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{38+\sqrt{106+\sqrt{206+\sqrt{338+\sqrt{502+…...}}}}}}$$
$$3=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{9+\sqrt{27+\sqrt{69+\sqrt{129+\sqrt{207+…...}}}}}}$$
$$3=\sqrt{4+1\sqrt{4+3\sqrt{4+5\sqrt{4+7\sqrt{4+9\sqrt{4+…...}}}}}}$$
$$3=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{18+\sqrt{40+\sqrt{70+\sqrt{108+\sqrt{156+…...}}}}}}$$
$$4=\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+\sqrt{12+…...}}}}}}$$
$$4=\sqrt{4+2\sqrt{4+4\sqrt{4+6\sqrt{4+8\sqrt{4+10\sqrt{4+…...}}}}}}$$
$$4=\sqrt{7+\sqrt{67+\sqrt{177+\sqrt{377+\sqrt{547+\sqrt{807+…...}}}}}}$$
$$4=\sqrt{8+\sqrt{52+\sqrt{128+\sqrt{236+\sqrt{376+\sqrt{548+…...}}}}}}$$
$$4=\sqrt{9+\sqrt{39+\sqrt{87+\sqrt{153+\sqrt{237+\sqrt{339+…...}}}}}}$$
$$4=\sqrt{10+\sqrt{28+\sqrt{54+\sqrt{88+\sqrt{130+\sqrt{180+…...}}}}}}$$
$$5=\sqrt{15+\sqrt{85+\sqrt{205+\sqrt{375+\sqrt{595+\sqrt{865+…...}}}}}}$$
$$5=\sqrt{16+\sqrt{68+\sqrt{152+\sqrt{268+\sqrt{416+\sqrt{596+…...}}}}}}$$
$$5=\sqrt{17+\sqrt{53+\sqrt{107+\sqrt{153+\sqrt{179+\sqrt{269+…...}}}}}}$$
$$6=\sqrt{25+\sqrt{105+\sqrt{235+\sqrt{415+\sqrt{645+\sqrt{925+…...}}}}}}$$
$$6=\sqrt{26+\sqrt{86+\sqrt{178+\sqrt{302+\sqrt{458+\sqrt{646+…...}}}}}}$$
$$7=\sqrt{37+\sqrt{127+\sqrt{267+\sqrt{457+\sqrt{697+\sqrt{987+…...}}}}}}$$

This is a comment not an answer. This will be tricky to find a closed form for. To see why let us consider a slight generalization of the ideas in @Chickenmancer's link.
For any $x,n,p$ we have that:
$$ (x+n)^2 = x^2 +n(x-p + (x+(n+p))$$
Therefore:
$$ x+n = \sqrt{x^2 +n(x-p + (x+(n+p))}$$
And therefore:
$$ x+n = \sqrt{x^2 +n(x-p + \sqrt{x^2 +(n+p)(x-p + \sqrt{x^2 +(n+2p)(x-p + \sqrt{...}}}}$$
Ramanujan's formulas are recovered by considering $x=p=1$ and $n=2$
Naively in order to engineer then some kind of closed form for your target series we want to find some functions $D,E,F,G$ s.t. for all choices of $x,n$
$$ F(x,n^2)^2 = D(x,1)+n^2(E(x,1)+G(x,1)F(x,(n+1)^2)$$
We then want to find an $x$ s.t. $D(x,1)=1, E(x,1)=0, G(x,1)=1$. So this is a system of 4 equations (1 functional equation, 3 boundary conditions on $x$) and 5 unknowns (4 functions, 1 complex number $x$). It then follows that $F(x,4)$ is the "closed form" of your nested radical.
Finding that collection of functions looks like it will be hard, and if I had to guess they will be non-elementary.
